# Is there a formal name for the product of the first N primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, terminology, factorial

I was wondering if there is a formal name for a composite number that is produced by multiplying the first N primes.

Examples:
6 = 2 * 3

30 = 2 * 3 * 5

210 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7

etc.

Almost like a factorial. Unfortunately the term "Factorial Prime" has a very different meaning.

Comment: Primorial is the name you are looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial

Comment: *Primorials*, also known as "*Goldbach-y numbers*" for fun because of their special goldbach properties where they are the sum of two primes. Go here $\longrightarrow$ https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PEMIxDjSRTQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called [primorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial).

To search for it, you could've gone to the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+6%2C+30%2C+210) and entered the first four of them. It's a handy tool for exactly this kind of thing.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for :) Big help! Been searching for a couple hours on my own with no luck. I have to wait 12 minutes before I mark this as the answer unfortunately...

Comment: Thanks for the OEIS link, I will bookmark it for the future :)

Comment: Technically, the primordial are the product of the primes $<n,$ so this is not the product of the first $n$ primes.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Tell that to my OEIS link above. Which yes, it does acknowledge your point. But it's still there.